# How to create automatically an apache cordova project via CLI through Java Command?

Tags: java, bash, cordova, build-automation, apache-cordova

I'd like to create a java library that wrapps the apache cordova CLI, but unfortunately I got stuck in some Java CMD problems and I'm not quite sure where to go next.

I am able to setup everything and create the project by calling

```
cordova create /my/project/path/ my-project-name
```

This automatically creates the basic roundup, which is already a nice thing.

Unfortunatly I'm not able to continue adding platforms to the project. When calling

```
"/bin/bash", 
"-c", 
"cd " + path.toString(), "cordova platform add " + os
```

as an array of Strings, the process continues with returncode 1, but nothing is being added and it doesn't depend on the **os** variable in the code, because I call this once with *android* and *ios*.

I've tried the code in Terminal and bash on my Mac and it works and correctly adds the platforms.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not really sure about the answer here but this question poped into my feed on java/cordova and what we worked on might be interesting to you https://www.codenameone.com/blog/phonegap-cordova-compatibility-for-codename-one.html its essentially a Cordova/Java hybrid with a cloud based build system.

Comment: Hi @ShaiAlmog, nice to meet you! I was investigating CodeName One for my masterthesis. I was mostly looking for the native part back than (2013) and i was/still am pretty interrested about your X-Platform Framework and dev tool :) Back to the topic; i need to create a build server on my own and i've pretty much created everything except the "adding a platform to the project" part. I really got stuck in this ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answere is fairly simple:

```
"/bin/bash", 
"-c", 
" cd " + path.toString() + " && cordova platform add " + os
```

If forgot to add an empty char before the cd-cmd and put everything in one line.